# How to run Flask-SuperAdmin example at local host?

Tags: python, flask, admin

I'm learning flask web app.

I find a flask extension called Flask-SuperAdmin from github https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/Flask-SuperAdmin

I've already fork it, but I don't know how to run Flask-SuperAdmin example at local host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fork it to run it; you fork it if you want to make changes to it or to fix a bug in it.

To install it, use the standard Python installation tools:

```
pip install Flask-SuperAdmin
```

Then, read the [quickstart section](http://flask-superadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) of the documentation to help you get started.